# Modeling, Faces rendering wrong. --> bad Face Layout?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, vertices, faces

i'm about to build a house model and i wanted to reduce faces. Maybe i reduced too much.
Faces are rendering bad. I checked the normals and they are all ok.

[image: bad rendering]

[image: wrong face layout?]

As you see, there are faces rendering differently on the right side. do they have to be connected? the top face goes all along the building where as the lower one goes to the entrance. Do they have to share vertices?

Is it a bad face layout? How can i make it better to avoid those bad faces?

edit:
added screen with flat shading:[image: Flat-Shading]

Comment: That panel in particular has the look of smooth shading. Is this intentional? If not, with the object selected, right click and select "shade flat".

Comment: im thinking about building this whole model new from scratch. as you see, the windows are just cutouts. maybe missing edges are the problem?

Comment: @dichterDichter Yes, that's the problem. Try use the knife tool to add some extra edges

Comment: I built it new from scratch. Just couldn't fix it.